# Getting the records from the last day, using Linq

Tags: linq

I want to get the records from the last day,. table is like this:

`ID - DateTime -------------- ItemId

-1 - 10/21/2012 12:08:10 PM - 45

-2 - 11/21/2012 11:20:18 AM - 30

-3 - 11/21/2012 11:50:00 AM - 11`

In this example, I want to get only rows 2 and 3. How can I do that?

**I want to get the entries from the LAST DAY only. This is dummy data.**

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea of how to do this. I'm new to linq.

Comment: In case linq you are not familiar with linq queries, provide input data structure. Also learn the basics from [Basic Linq Query Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: A better question to ask them would be "how to learn more about LINQ" but that's already been asked many times on StackOverflow, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn+linq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var lastDayItems = itmes.GroupBy(i => i.DateTime.Date)
                        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                        .First();
```

OR

```
var date = items.Max(i => i.DateTime).Date;
var lastDayItems = itmes.Where(i => i.DateTime.Date == date);
```

Comment: I want to get LAST DAY entries. These are dummy data

Comment: @Darshana then why are you writing this comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) followed by [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

Example

```
 int[] ints = new [] {1,2,3};  
 var last = ints.Skip(1).Take(2).
```

---

Updates based on comments

> I want to get LAST DAY entries. These are dummy data

Then use [Last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) method.
Example

```
 int[] ints = new [] {1,2,3};  
 var last = ints.Last().
```

Comment: I want to get LAST DAY entries. These are dummy data